# edb Linux Follow in Dump for register EAX going to different address (logical or physical)

Tags: linux, debugging, memory, x86, edb

My issue is with memory location values displayed in the *Registers* and *Dump* windows in `edb` on Linux.
With my process paused, register `EAX` contains `b77190a0`. This address points to within a buffer.

I do a *Follow In Dump* for `EAX` to display the contents from the address in `EAX`.
In *Dump* view, the expected contents are displayed but at the address `b750da0e`.

I've read: [Difference between logical addresses, and physical addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697729/difference-between-logical-addresses-and-physical-addresses)
The conclusion I have come to is that `EAX` contains a logical address (for the process) which gets evaluated to the physical address shown in *Dump* View.

Is this the right basic thinking or am I missing something else?
I have used Immunity Debugger on x86 windows without this behaviour following register addresses.

Comment: You're right that any address your process will have in a register is a logical address.  Don't even think about physical memory, just think about your process's memory as a flat 4GB space that your process owns all of.  (It's not really, and a 32bit kernel won't let you map the upper 1GB of your virtual address space, IIRC, but this mental model is good enough.)

Comment: I don't use EDB, so I have no idea what you're asking.  Where did `b750da0e` come from, if it wasn't in `eax`?  Is `eax` maybe pointing part way in to a large buffer?

Comment: I tried recreating the issue and _Follow in Dump_ now goes to the address in the register as initially expected! Please see screenshot at [imgur.com/0kExhZ9](http://imgur.com/0kExhZ9) Note in the screenshot, I am observing `ECX`, but that behaviour is the same for `EAX`.

Comment: Did you single-step past an instruction that modified `eax` before?  If the dump window moves to follow the register value, maybe you didn't re-check the register?  Anyway, voting to close as non-reproducible.  It might be user-error or a bug in edb.  Questions about how to use development software are not what SO is nominally for, I think.  (Although there are a lot of git questions.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Peter. Hold off on that vote for a moment as I can confirm it's not user error, see the screenshot reproducing a similar occurrence: http://imgur.com/9t8ZmfJ

Comment: Looks fishy, although I don't use that debugger.  I think I tried it once, I forget why I didn't keep using it.  Anyway, go report a bug on the edb page.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of edb. So to answer your question. No edb does not have any concern about physical addresses. I've never seen this behavior before, so if it is acting as your describe, then it is likely a bug.

Comment: Thanks Evan, I'll put some info together for you.